# Permutation representation and point stabilizer

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, representation-theory, group-actions

In the [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/0705.4122) by Ben Elias et al. (2010), Page 2, the minimal faithful permutation representation is defined.

Later it is mentioned that, choosing a point stabilizer subgroup in each orbit, it is clear that minimal faithful permutation representations corresponds to collections $\mathcal{H}$ of subgroup of $G$, which gives $d(G)$. Here, $d(G)$ is the least integer such that $G$ can be embedded in $S_d$.

Question: I did not get, how does some collection of point stabilizers gives a minimal faithful permutation representations of $G$.

E.g., Let $G =\langle (1,4)(2,5)(3,6),(1,3,2)(4,5,6) \rangle \leq S_6$. Then $G\cong S_3$ and it is transitive subgroup in $S_6$. Thus the orbit is $\Omega=\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$. The action $\chi: G \times \{\Omega\} \to \{\Omega\}$ and $G_{\Omega}=\{e\}$. But the collection
$\{G_{\Omega}\}$ does not give $d(G)$ (here $d(G)$ is 3).

I think I am not interpreting the definition correctly.

Can someone clear my doubt? Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You are trying to read more into the statement than it says. Any permutation representation of any group is determined up to equivalence by the point stabilizers of the orbits of the representation, and so this applies in particular to a minimal degree representation. According to your interpretation every permutation representation would be of minimal degree, which is clearly false.